# Where can I find a data set containing wetland loss by decade

Tags: human-influence

I am trying to find a reputable source that lists how many  acres of wetland are destroyed each year on average in each decade, specifically in the Continental US. I found some secondary sources, but many of them are conflicting, and didn't list primary sources. Are there any primary sources that list the amount of wetland destruction?

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stackexchange! Could you specify whether you are looking for global or regional data? In the first case: Are you looking for spatial resolved data (If yes, in which resolution?)? In the second case: For which region do you need the data? Please edit your question accordingly. Thanks :-)

Comment: @daniel.neumann Added the information to my post

Comment: Its difficult to respond, beyond just echoing a google search, without knowing what information you have considered or are discounting. You might do better with a question asking for clarification about specific conflicts you have found between the sources you are looking at?

Answer (score 1):

Start with US Fish and wildlife services National Wetlands Inventory site.
Site has links to :

1. [Wetlands Mapper](https://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/Mapper.html).
2. [National Wetlands Inventory home page](https://www.fws.gov/wetlands/index.html)
3. [Status and Trends web page](https://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Status-and-Trends/index.html)
4. [Download Seamless Wetlands Data](https://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/Data-Download.html)